# Grails view generation for domain class doesn't include all attributes

Tags: grails

I am trying to setup and re-engineer an older java project into grails. I use GGTS 3.1.0.Release and I have configured my domain models. My problem is that when I use the automatic generation of controller and views (right click on project->new-> generate controller and views) , It does generates the files but the attributes are not all included! I thought that this scaffolding would make available a view with all the attributes of my domain class. Am I wrong?

Associate class:

```
package com.trading.core

class Associate {

    Integer id
    String name
    String address
    Prefecture prefecture
    SubPrefecture subPrefecture
    Municipal municipal
    String city
    BigDecimal minDiscount
    String zipcode
    User insUser
    Date insDatetime
    User updtUser
    Date updtDatetime

    static mapping = {
        table "associate"
        id generator: 'identity'
        minDiscount column:"min_discount"
        insUser column: "ins_user"
        insDatetime column: "ins_datetime"
        updtUser column: "updt_user"
        updtDatetime column: "updt_datetime"

        municipal column: "municipal"
        subPrefecture column: "sub_prefecture"
        prefecture column: "prefecture"

        version false
    }       

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

list.gsp (generated)

```
<%@ page import="com.trading.core.Associate" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="layout" content="main">
        <g:set var="entityName" value="${message(code: 'associate.label', default: 'Associate')}" />
        <title><g:message code="default.list.label" args="[entityName]" /></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="#list-associate" class="skip" tabindex="-1"><g:message code="default.link.skip.label" default="Skip to content&hellip;"/></a>
        <div class="nav" role="navigation">
            <ul>
                <li><a class="home" href="${createLink(uri: '/')}"><g:message code="default.home.label"/></a></li>
                <li><g:link class="create" action="create"><g:message code="default.new.label" args="[entityName]" /></g:link></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="list-associate" class="content scaffold-list" role="main">
            <h1><g:message code="default.list.label" args="[entityName]" /></h1>
            <g:if test="${flash.message}">
            <div class="message" role="status">${flash.message}</div>
            </g:if>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>

                        <g:sortableColumn property="name" title="${message(code: 'associate.name.label', default: 'Name')}" />

                        <g:sortableColumn property="address" title="${message(code: 'associate.address.label', default: 'Address')}" />

                        <g:sortableColumn property="city" title="${message(code: 'associate.city.label', default: 'City')}" />

                        <g:sortableColumn property="insDatetime" title="${message(code: 'associate.insDatetime.label', default: 'Ins Datetime')}" />

                        <th><g:message code="associate.insUser.label" default="Ins User" /></th>

                        <g:sortableColumn property="minDiscount" title="${message(code: 'associate.minDiscount.label', default: 'Min Discount')}" />

                        <th><g:message code="associate.municipal.label" default="Municipal" /></th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <g:each in="${associateInstanceList}" status="i" var="associateInstance">
                    <tr class="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'}">

                        <td><g:link action="show" id="${associateInstance.id}">${fieldValue(bean: associateInstance, field: "address")}</g:link></td>

                        <td>${fieldValue(bean: associateInstance, field: "city")}</td>

                        <td><g:formatDate date="${associateInstance.insDatetime}" /></td>

                        <td>${fieldValue(bean: associateInstance, field: "insUser")}</td>

                        <td>${fieldValue(bean: associateInstance, field: "minDiscount")}</td>

                        <td>${fieldValue(bean: associateInstance, field: "municipal")}</td>

                    </tr>
                </g:each>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <div class="pagination">
                <g:paginate total="${associateInstanceTotal}" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Unrelated - why have you mapped the table name and every column name to the same names that would have been used without any configuration?

Answer (score 2):

The scaffolding defaults to showing only some of the properties - I thought it was 6.  To change this run the command

```
grails install-templates
```

Then look in the `src/templates/scaffolding` and you will see `list.gsp`

You can edit that file and remove or modify how the views are generated (look for `i < 6` in the code for this issue).  Then next time you generate views that template will be used and show whatever number of properties you set.